# haskell xml update text using HXT library

Tags: xml, haskell

I need to have a possibility to update text in structure like this `<node><data key="attr">text</data></node>`. Is there any way to do this by using HXT library in haskell?

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow - this is a platform, where people answer questions and help each other for free. So please put **at least** as much effort into your question as you would expect someone answering it. You can show us what you have tried, what the great search engine has told you or not. You can reference documentation you do not understand or where you are stuck in general. Right now the effort I would put into an answer based on your effort is: "I think it is possible to do that."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural answer is a lens library; I don't think `hxt` has such a thing associated with it.  But there is `xml-lens` which uses `xml-conduit` (but not conduits in fact)

The examples in the readme https://github.com/fumieval/xml-lens are fairly straightforward, but maybe a bit operator-clogged, if you aren't familiar with lenses. But here is less dense version of one of the examples. It modifies each page number in a book list by adding "  pages" to it, changing

```
  <pages>360</pages>
```

to

```
  <pages>360 pages</pages>
```

starting with an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<books>
<book category="Textbooks">
    <title>Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!</title>
    <author year="2011">Miran Lipovaca</author>
    <pages>360</pages>
</book>
<book category="Textbooks">
    <title>Programming in Haskell</title>
    <author year="2007">Graham Hutton</author>
    <pages>200</pages>
</book>
</books>
```

We need imports like these

```
  >>> import Text.XML.Lens        -- from the lens-xml package
  >>> import Control.Lens         -- from the lens package
  >>> import Text.XML             -- from the xml-conduit package
  >>> import Data.Monoid ((<>))
  >>> import qualified Data.Text as T
  >>> import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BL
  >>> :set -XOverloadedStrings    -- for Text literals
```

First I define the traversal that targets what I want to change:

```
  >>> let my_focus = root . el "books" ./ el "book" ./ el "pages" . text
```

then I define an ordinary Haskell function in terms of it, using `over some_traversal some_function`

```
  >>> let my_transformation = over my_focus (<> " pages") -- i.e. apply (<> " pages") to
  >>> :t my_transformation                                -- all the focused positions
  my_transformation :: Document -> Document
```

read the document:

```
  >>> doc <- Text.XML.readFile def "book.xml" 
  >>> :t doc
  doc :: Document
```

and then transform and render it:

```
  >>> BL.putStrLn $ renderLBS def (my_transformation doc)
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><books>
  <book category="Textbooks">
      <title>Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!</title>
      <author year="2011">Miran Lipovaca</author>
      <pages>360 pages</pages>
  </book>
  <book category="Textbooks">
      <title>Programming in Haskell</title>
      <author year="2007">Graham Hutton</author>
      <pages>200 pages</pages>
  </book>
  </books>
```

This might be a little slow given the fancy apparatus it is using below the surface, but is plainly crazy powerful.

Comment: I don't know if things have changed in the meantime but the function `./` does not seem to exist any more. Any chance you could give an update?